# How to output a list to vuetify data-table?

Tags: json, list, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

Using `vue.js`, `vuetify data-table`, `axios` and `express`, I have build a table [according to the official vuetify data-table example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#data-table). With `axios` I request the data and everything works fine, the `express` server generates a list, which has a few recurring values:

```
[
    "id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60",
    "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70",
    "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20",
    ...
]
```

Now I have two questions:

1. How to put the data into the table?
2. Is a `list` suitable for this operation or should I better generate a `json` object? If a list is not suitable, what is the best way to display the json object to the data-table?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to have your data in JSON. This is a basic way of doing it:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'ID' },
        { text: 'Date' },
        { text: 'Name' },
        { text: 'Price' }
      ],
      listItems: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('data.json')
      .then(response => (this.listItems = response.data))
  }
})
```

So you have your headers already in the data, then when your app is mounted axios loads the JSON data and passes it to the listItems. Then your vuetify will be like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="listItems"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.date }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.price }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed property to paginate your `listItems` which give something like

```
[
    ["id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60"],
    ["id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70"],
    ["id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20"],
    ...
]
```

then convert each inner array to an object by adding the appropriate keys :

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "date": "01-01-2019",
    "name": "name1",
    "amount": "€ 5,60"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "date": "02-01-2019",
    "name": "name2",
    "amount": "€ 5,70"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "date": "03-01-2019",
    "name": "name3",
    "amount": "€ 5,20"
  }
]
```

**Running example**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'ID',
          value: 'id'
        },
        {
          text: 'Date',
          value: 'data'
        },
        {
          text: 'Name',
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Amount',
          value: 'amount'
        }
      ],
      listItems: [
        "id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60",
        "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70",
        "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20"

      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      let items = [];
      let j = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.listItems.length; i = i + 4) {
        items[j] = this.listItems.slice(i, i + 4);
        j++;
      }
      let tmp = items.map((item, i) => {
        let ob = {};
        item.forEach((t, k) => {

          k % 4 == 0 ? ob.id = t : {};
          k % 4 == 1 ? ob.date = t : {};
          k % 4 == 2 ? ob.name = t : {};
          k % 4 == 3 ? ob.amount = t : {};

        })
        return ob;
      });
   
      return tmp;


    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app" data-app>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" class="elevation-1">
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.date }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.amount }}</td>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>

</div>
```